# Бэкап и подключение к базе другими СУБД

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-server, sqlite

Вопрос такой: можно ли к серверу, который создан еще на версии MS SQL 2003 года, подключиться не только с MS SQL, но и с постгреса или какой-либо другой СУБД? И можно ли бэкап базы развернуть на других СУБД, заметил что bak - фишка только MS SQL. Да и файлы mdf не любят.

Comment: Нужен как минимум бекап в виде sql файлов, т.е. просто текст в виде create table и insert. Но и при этом нем гарантии, что он может быть один к одному, без изменений загружен на другую СУБД, так как у них могут не совпадать какие либо типы данных, быть другой синтаксис объявления внешних ключей и некоторых других объектов. Кроме того, если в БД была использована какая либо серверная логика на хранимых процедурах, то ее надо будет руками переписать на другой язык, так как языки хранимых процедур всех СУБД сильно отличаются

Comment: Я так понимаю, подключение невозможно? Про запросы думал, но для 300к строк инсерты? Звучит жестко.

Comment: Если под "подключение" вы имеете ввиду взять файл от ms sql и перенести под другую СУБД то конечно невозможно. Ибо СУБД в первую очередь это ее уникальный формат хранения данных с которым она умеет работать и он может отличаться даже между соседними версиями одной СУБД (и даже на одной версии на разных платформах). 300k это вообще ни о чем. Мы как то за 8 часов перелили инсертами 150 млн записей, с доп обработкой, на обычном, не навороченном сервере. Главное если индексов много, то в таблице изначально только первичный ключ сделать, а остальные индексы создавать уже после заливки данных